# Having trouble with highstock and json

Tags: jquery, json, getjson, jsfiddle

This is the code i currently have within jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/syleron/5MyXp/

if anyone could help me actually show the graph with the correct data that would be fantastic!

Comment: For starters, you aren't using the jQuery framework in jsfiddle. When you do, its a cross domain error so you need to supply a jsonp callback.

Comment: Also, please paste your code in SO as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boy!  Lots of problems with your fiddle.  The first, as Mark pointed out, you were linking in Mootools, not jQuery.  Then, once that was fixed, the AJAX call failed because it is a cross-domain request, as Mark also pointed out.

To get your fiddle working, I got the JSON data from your source directly, and just put that into a variable to avoid the cross-domain request.  But it still didn't work!

The problem, as it turns out is that your data has descending times, and apparently Highstock can't handle that.  The solution then, was simple.  In the loop in which you populate your series, instead of counting up with:

```
for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
```

I just changed it to count backwards:

```
for (i = dataLength-1; i > 0; i--) {
```

And that solved the problem.  Here's a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gV9xC/

Comment: Wouldn't a sort be safer? High stock can not handle out of order date ranges. Also if you use a logarithmic y-axis it can't plot 0 values either. Run into both those issues before.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the support I have definitely learned a thing or two :)

Answer (score 1):

You are making a cross-domain request, to allow for that you need to make the request as jsonp by providing a callback.

Add `&callback=?` to the end of your url. However, that won't fix your jsfiddle demo because you need to simulate ajax requests with jsfiddle. They have a API doc for that.